# C# programmatically initializing multidimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create an array like this:

```
3,100,21,0
0,100,17,22
9,80,9,44
```

etc. I need to do this in a for loop where I calculate the different values. The length (no of rows) is not set at design time. Could be 1, could be 500 etc.

I suspect this is quite easy but...?

How does that calculation work? I'm not sure how that is relevant? I mean, the number of rows is calculated at run time, the first value is from a sorted List; the 2nd value is fixed (at run time) except for one of them which is not; taht is, the second values are all the same but one; the third value is calculated in a function and the fourth is an arithmetic value, a sum.

Design time as opposed to run time.

Ron

Comment: **where I calculate the different values** : and how does that calculation work exactly?

Comment: Does your for loop has an iteration count? You could use it to set the array length.

Comment: You're right, populating a 2 dimensional array *is* easy. Did you try anything? What is "design time"??

Comment: do you have four column or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decide on the size of the array at runtime, but once you create it, it will become immutable, and you won't be able to change the size of the dimensions.

```
int z = ... ;
int[,] array = new int[get1stDimensionLength(), z];
// programmatically fill the array
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++) {
        array[i,j] = 18;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly OK. I just need to know how to populate the rows.

Comment: You can just run two for loops, obtaining the dimensions sizes via GetLength(). I expanded on the example in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with Generic List like this

```
 public struct MyArray<T1> 
{
        public void Init (T1 f, T1 s, T1 th, T1 fo)
        {
            First = f;
            Second = s;
            Third = th;
            Forth = fo;
        }
        public T1 First { get; set; }
        public T1 Second { get; set; }
        public T1 Third { get; set; }
        public T1 Forth { get; set; }

}
```

and here you can set an array with undetermined size at compile time

```
 List<MyArray<Int32>> list = new List<MyArray<int>>();
```